# Pyspark Configuration Issue in Eclipse

Tags: python, sql, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have followed below path for installation of pyspark in Eclipse
https://enahwe.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-developing-with-python-and-spark-on-hadoop/

**My Eclipse Configurations are below**

```
SPARK_HOME:C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS:--master local[*] --queue PyDevSpark1.5.2 pyspark-shell
SPARK_CONF_DIR:C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\conf
```

I am in corporate network for your info.

Now, after successfull installation and configuration When I run any program I get below error

> Using Spark's default log4j profile:
>   org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>       Setting default log level to "WARN".
>       To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
>       17/06/19 17:26:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable
>       C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
>       17/06/19 17:26:49 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
>       java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>         ... 18 more
>       17/06/19 17:26:49 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>       java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>         ... 18 more
>       17/06/19 17:26:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python":
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>         ... 18 more
>
> ```
> 17/06/19 17:26:49 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\01 Delivery Support\01 easyJet\SparkEclipseWorkspace\SparkTestPrograms\src\MyWordCounts.py",
> ```
>
> line 24, in 
>           for wc in wordCounts.collect(): print wc
>         File "C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 776, in collect
>           port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
>         File "C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 933, in **call**
>         File "C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
>       : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost
>   task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Cannot
>   run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find
>   the file specified
>
> ```
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>
>   ... 18 more
>
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
>
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
>
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>   at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
>
>   at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>
>   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
>
>   at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
>
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>
>   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
>
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>
>   ... 1 more
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
>
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>
>   ... 18 more
>
>
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 11040 (child process of PID 3216) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 3216 (child process of PID 5168) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 5168 (child process of PID 6492) has been terminated.
> ```

Comment: what do you get running python in your console ?

Comment: On execution of below lines
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
spark = spark.builder.appName("example-spark").config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true").config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir',"file:///C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/metastore_db/spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()
student_df1 = spark.read.csv("file:///D:/01 Delivery Support/01 easyJet/data/student1.csv", header="false",inferSchema = True,sep=',')
WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not a

Comment: On execution of below lines in cosole
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

spark = spark.builder.appName("example-spark").config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true").config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir',"file:///C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/metastore_db/spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()
student_df1 = spark.read.csv("file:///D:/01 Delivery Support/01 easyJet/data/student1.csv", header="false",inferSchema = True,sep=',')
WARN Hive: 
Failed to access metastore.I get above error.But the same code has worked in my personal pc